# AngularJS removing # with htaccess and parameter

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have a little problem. I have a website built with angularjs and my urls has a #.

I used html5 mode to remove it. Now i want to make some changes in the htaccess file but i have a problem with my url parameters.

This is my url:

http://myname.co/infosystem/www/app/#/static/randomcompany

and i want this url:

http://myname.co/infosystem/www/app/static/randomcompany

And my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://myname.co/infosystem/www/app/static/ [R=301,L]
```

i think removing the hash works. but i have no idea how to get the 'randomcompany'.

i just want to take the parameter and pass it equal to the new url. Without adding something. Just the /static/abc /static/xyz

It would be very nice if someone could help me :)

Comment: What is the location of your htaccess file?